# Table cell height match background height

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a table with one of the cells containing a background image.  The width of the cell is set to be 100% of the page's width, and the background-size for the image is set to 100%.  This results in a background image where the width of that image is scaled to match the width of the page.

I'm having troubles with the height though.

I'd like the height of the cell to be the height of the scaled image.  This would result in a cell with a width and height matching the width and height of the scaled image.  The scaled image should always maintain its aspect ratio.

How can this be done using CSS?

Edit:

The website I'm modelling after is essentially http://www.vassar.edu/ .  The primary image in the center of the screen is what I'm trying to model.  I want to be able to place text on top of this image.

Here's the relevant HTML and CSS:

```
td.content
{
    vertical-align:  top;
    text-align:      left;
    font-family:     "Arial";
    font-style:      normal;
    font-size:       0.9em;
    background:      url('/pages/home/intro_image.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
    width:           100%;
}

table.content_document
{
    width:            50%;
    padding:          0px;
    margin-top:       2em;
    border:           solid thin grey;
    border-radius:    0.5em;
    box-shadow:       black 0.5em 0.5em 0.3em;
    background-color: white;
    padding:          1em;
    position:         relative;
}

td.content_text_cell
{
    overflow: scroll;
}

<table>
    <tr class="content">
        <td class="content" colspan="2">
            <table class="content_document">
                <tr>
                    <td class="content_text_cell">
                        <p>
                            This is a simple test
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: I think that it has to do with the overflow option. Do you mind sharing the table HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done if you add the image as a background image.
But if it is a img element inside the table cell, then the cell height would differ to the image height.

Here's a [Fiddle added](http://jsfiddle.net/Yuss8/).